# Puppeteer: What do the round brackets enclosing an async function mean?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I can't figure out what these round brackets enclosing an async function are for. What are they denoting?

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async() => {

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  // more codes here
})();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're seeing is called an [Immediately Invoked Function Expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately_invoked_function_expression). They want to run this code right away, and so there's a pair of `()` at the end in order to immediately call the function. But just adding those would result in illegal syntax,  so in addition the function as a whole needs to be wrapped in parentheses.

If you're curious why they are creating a function just to immediately call it, they're doing it in order to be able to use the `await` keyword. Await can only be used in an async function, and therefore can't be at the root level of a file. There are other reasons which can motivate the use of an IIFE, but that's the reason in this case.

Comment: I use it multiple times every day. It's been a life saver so far :D